# How to work on the same array across the recursion stack (or: How to pass a partial solution to the previous/next recursive call to method)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

In a method (that I wrote so far):

```
private int[] calculateSum(int[] array, int index) {
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    if (index > 0) { //implicit break condition
        calculateSum(array, index-1);
        result[index] = array[index]+result[index-1]; //should be sum of array values up until array[index]
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am supposed to populate the new array based on the elements of the argument array, and return the new array.

But, how can I keep returning the partially populated array `result` to the previous recursive call?
When this code runs, a new array `result` is being created in each recursive call. I can't use helper methods, global variables, or anything except the method as it is defined.

Generally (and most importantly) how do I pass the partial/current solution to the next method call if I can't use accumulator, or any extra variables? If I create a variable inside the method, every subsequent recursive call creates a new variable, the values of which I can't pass to the previous frame.

Another typical example is:
count the number of zeroes in a given integer recursively using only the method with the signature:

```
int noZeroes(int x) {}
```

All the sources I found incl. R.Sedgewick, E.S.Roberts, M.T.Goodrich et al. use different 'helper structures' in the examples, so I can't find any instructions on how to deal with recursion with 'limited' resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `i` and `index` are supposed to be the same thing here.

What you are missing is using the array returned by `calculateSum(array, i-1)`.

The idea is to create a single array at the end of the recursion, add to keep modifying that array on each recursive call:

```
private int[] calculateSum(int[] array, int index) 
{
    if (index == 0) {
        return Arrays.copyOf (array, array.length);
    } else {
        int[] result = calculateSum(array, index-1);
        result[index] += result[index-1];
        return result;
    }
}
```

When you reach the end of the recursion, you create a copy of the input array. That's the array you return. Then, you modify one element of the array each time a recursive call returns.

For the input:

```
{1,2,3,4,3}
```

this method will return:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 13]
```

- When `index == 0`, you return a copy of the original array: `{1,2,3,4,3}`.
- When `index == 1`, you add `result[0]` to `result[1]` and return: `{1,3,3,4,3}`.
- When `index == 2`, you add `result[1]` to `result[2]` and return: `{1,3,6,4,3}`.
- When `index == 3`, you add `result[2]` to `result[3]` and return: `{1,3,6,10,3}`.
- When `index == 4`, you add `result[3]` to `result[4]` and return: `{1,3,6,10,13}`.

BTW, if you are allowed to modify the input array, you can change this method to a `void` method, and the input array will contain the result:

```
private void calculateSum(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        calculateSum(array, index-1);
        array[index] += array[index-1];
    }
}
```